# What do the `echo $?` and `ls >> $File 2>&1` commands do?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, echo

Can someone help me with understanding this.

`echo $?` -- I know it outputs a variable of some kind...

and this

`ls >> $File 2>&1`  ----  can someone explain what this does?

Comment: you are making two different questions, each one have possible duplicates in StackExchange

Comment: exactly. And they are fairly basic. No idea why this was modded up.

Comment: @lese no such thing as a cross-site duplicate. If the question already exists and has been answered on another site of the SE network, copy the answer (with attribution) and post it here.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro basic questions are welcome here. There is no minimum level of expertise needed to post on U&L. We cater to the newbies and the gurus alike. Yes, the OP is asking two separate questions and that's bad. Yes, the 1st one is trivial to find by searching the man page or the internet. The second, however, is not that simple to answer if you don't know what terms to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1. Use [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/):

- [echo $?](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo%20%24%3F)
- [ls >> $File 2>&1](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ls%20%3E%3E%20%24File%202%3E%261)

or

## 2. Search the man page of your shell

by doing:

```
    $ man sh #replace sh with another shell if you need to
```

You can search for a pattern Ctrl-F style by pressing `/`, typing the search pattern and then pressing enter.

---

## Summary:

> **echo**: display a line of text
>
> **$?**: expands to the exit status of the most recently executed command/pipeline
>
> **ls**: list directory contents
>
> **>>**: append output
>
> **2>&1**: redirecting stderr (fd=2) to stdout (fd=1) (which is "$File" in append mode in this context)

Comment: Pleas don't put link only answer. You can see that answers `barely more than a link to an external site` can be deleted.

Comment: @PhoneixS Added the word *use* without wrapping it in a link.

Comment: strange that explainshell.com doesn't know about -x option in ksh ... (not in OP)

Comment: @SPRBRN Yes I know, but what happened if the web is closed. It must add more information about what the commands do so in case of explainshell (god forbid!) is closed we still have an usable answer.

Comment: @Archemar `set -x` works.

Comment: + There are always man pages. I rarely use web services if I can get an answer locally, but this seemed like a nice fit for the website.

Comment: Adding one word is hardly an improvement! Please don't post link-only answers. They are dependent on the link working and become useless if it ever breaks. They're also [not answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/203101), they're directions for where an answer can be found. Please edit your answer and include the relevant information.

Comment: @terdon And vague questions of the "what does this code do" type aren't good questions by the StackOverflow definition of a good question. We're in undefined territory here.

Comment: Indeed. A close vote for "too broad" would make sense here. I'm just saying that if you do choose to answer, please write an actual answer. If you're just providing links, add them as comments instead. Just like the recent edit did.

Comment: The OP had the problem of finding out what "some" shell code does. I consider a link to explainshell.com a better solution to that than actually answering the specifics so I stand by my original answer. Specific questions (99.9% of other questions I've answered) I answer in accordance with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: @PSkocik in accordance with that meta question you should also answer this question with an explanation of the commands (give them the rod but also the fish, in case the rod is lost). If you you want to talk more about this topic, tell me in the chat.

Comment: @PhoneixS Speaking about rules, you're not supposed to edit other people's question to the point that you completely change them either. In any case, I believe rathdowney  should be more than well equipped to start plundering the seas now.

Comment: It is not always easy to ask question on a topic you don't grasp. OP get answered, that is the main point. I had same lack of understanding thirty years ago, but U&L was not here.

Answer (score 5):

echo `$?` will return error code from previous command.

try

```
false ; echo $?
true ; echo $?
```

`ls >> $File 2>&1`, will redirect  ( `>>`) output of ls to end of a file whose name is in `$File`, `2>&1` will redirect error as well, if any.

- `>>` stand for append to file.

Answer (score 2):

What sinks in more in this question is an issue to do with redirection operators.

```
ls >> $File 2>&1

ls stands for list contents of current directory

>> means append to end of file

$FILE means there is a variable declared as FILE having some value, could be the path to a file.

2>&1 means redirecting both stdin and sterr to the target file, in this case $FILE.
```